# Issues with query order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-server-2014

I have to order the following categories like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6A
6B
6C
6D
7A
7B
10
11
12
```

How would I accomplish this via a SQL query?

I have tried:

```
Select * 
From table 
Order By len(category_name), category_name
```

But they order like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
10
11
12
6A
6B
6C
6D
7A
7B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **Scalar-Valued Function** (more info about scalar-valued functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)) that removes letters from your categories' names (more information about this specific function [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/01/sql-server-how-to-remove-all-characters-from-a-string-using-t-sql/)) and use the result to order your data:

```sql
--1. declare a new function that removes all letters from your category name
--1.1 if the function already exists delete it
if OBJECT_ID('fx_remove_letters') is not null
drop function fx_remove_letters

go
--1.2 create a function to remove all letters (CHAR(65) is letter A, char(90) is letter Z)
create function fx_remove_letters(@str NVARCHAR(max))
returns  NVARCHAR(max)
as
begin
    DECLARE @loop INT
    SET @loop = 0
    WHILE @loop < 26
        BEGIN
        SET @str = REPLACE(@str, CHAR(65 + @loop), '')
        SET @loop = @loop + 1
        END
    return @str
end
go
--2. this table variable holds your categories in a random order
declare @tmp table (category_name nvarchar(10))

--3. populate the test table variable 
insert into @tmp 
values('6D'),('2'),('3'),('12'),('5'),('6C'),('6B'),
      ('1'),('7A'),('4'),('7B'),('10'),('11'),('6A')

--4. select your data ordering them with the function we defined at the beginning
select category_name 
from @tmp 
order by cast(dbo.fx_remove_letters(category_name) as int), category_name
```

Here is the table before ordering:

[image]

Now the results after the `order by`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful.?

```
SELECT category_name
FROM #Table1
ORDER BY 
    CASE ISNUMERIC(category_name) 
        WHEN 1 THEN REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(category_name)) + category_name       
        ELSE REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(category_name)+1) + category_name     
    END
```

If you have '6AA','6AB'.. etc in your input you can use below query:

```
SELECT category_name
    FROM #Table1
    ORDER BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(category_name) =1 
                THEN REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(category_name)) + category_name
            ELSE 
                REPLICATE('0', 10 - LEN(category_name)+LEN(STUFF(category_name, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]%',category_name),1,''))) + category_name   
        END
```